# best approach to resolve 503 errors returned from kubernetes pods through ingress nginx

Tags: http, kubernetes, streaming

I have setup a small k8s cluster that has an application deployed which accepts incoming http request. There is an ingress load balancer in front of this cluster and although the application seemed to initially work, the users are complaining of multiple 503 errors when trying to send an http request and connect.

I can confirm these errors in the logs. The application is setup to accept an incoming request with proper authentication and use an active pod to initiate and transmit the streaming data. What I have deduced is that the users are sending multiple requests every few seconds which then results in these errors and have advised them not to.

My question is this:

- when the request is received, k8s send request to first pod if pod is
  streaming,
- request is rejected by pod with 503 k8s then send this
  request to next pod
- if second pod is streming it reject request with
  503 and so on
- if N-th pod is not streaming and k8s send request to
  it, it accepts  request and start streaming
- if that customers
  particular request was already accepted previously, it returns a 404
  error.

Based on the logic flow above, does this seem like a good architectural setup and efficient process flow?